Can one be sued for destroying illegal goods?
Consider this story:

One evening, Bob walks trough the park and witnesses how a man apparently sells drugs to a group of minors. As he approaches, the man runs away, but Bob catches up on the minors. He gives them a sermon about drug abuse they won't forget for a while. At the end, they more or less voluntarily hand him over their merchandise. As he walks away, Bob disposes off the drugs and considers the issue resolved.


However, the next day, one of the minors reconsiders the story and wants to sue Bob for destroying his property. He requests Bob to pay $200 or the equivalent in narcotics.

Does Bob have to fear anything? Could he be liable? To keep it simple, we can assume that the drug in question is illegal to sell, use or own in any quantity.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


Does Bob have to fear anything? Could he be liable?

Bob doesn't have to worry about a civil suit for conversion or civil theft.
He may have to worry about criminal liability for drug possession, depending upon the nuances of the applicable statutes and defenses.

Lots of interesting twists in here. Are the minors trying to sue or their legal guardians? Did a legal sale happen between the dealer and the minors, or can the legal guardian rescind that and ask for money back from the dealer? What was the value of the drugs, for legal purposes? Did Bob tamper with criminal evidence, and if so was that justified by his attempt to stop the crime of drug use? Apparently the children knew Bob, would the relationship be close enough that he would not have to testify against them in criminal court?

@o.m. "Are the minors trying to sue or their legal guardians?" Doesn't matter. "Did a legal sale happen between the dealer and the minors," No. "can the legal guardian rescind that and ask for money back from the dealer?" Maybe, if they can find the dealer who has much bigger worries from the criminal law (an adult buyer couldn't sue the dealer). "Did Bob tamper with criminal evidence, and if so was that justified by his attempt to stop the crime of drug use?" Fair question, maybe. "would the relationship be close enough that he would not have to testify against them in criminal court?" No.

@ohwilleke "Bob doesn't have to worry about a civil suit for conversion or civil theft." Can you explain why? Because there was never a contract between the dealer and the boy, nor between the boy and Bob (as contracts about the purchase of drugs are void) or because of some other reason?

@PMF Because you can't sue for something that you weren't entitled to own. Probably under the doctrine of unclean hands in jurisdictions where equitable defenses can be applied to claims arising in law, although there is probably more than one legal theory that could justify it.

@ohwilleke, assuming the minors are below the age of criminal responsibility (improbable in Switzerland, AFAIK), they might decide to admit to having had drugs, and claim that Bob pressured them into giving them over. Can illegal drugs be property in Switzerland?

@o.m. "Can illegal drugs be property in Switzerland?" I would be stunned if children could have any legal rights in illegal drugs in their possession that would give rise to a lawsuit. Switzerland probably has a formal right to seize them from children for their own protection.

@ohwilleke, wouldn't that be an administrative act by the police, i's dotted and t's crossed? Imagine it was guns, not drugs. Any sane adult would take them away from children, but that transfer of physical control is not a transfer of property. So are drugs (unlike guns) incapable of being owned, or is it that ownership of drugs is punished? How do the Swiss construct their law?

@o.m. I am more certain of the end result than I am of the path by which the Swiss get there (which might even differ from canton to canton).
